# What is better between Chukwa & Scribe?

Tags: logging, hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

I am using Hadoop , but for logging i need something.
But i don't know which is better system for logging in between **Scribe** and **Chukwa**.
Can you guys please tell me?
And if there are any alternatives which are easy to mingle with Hadoop please let me know.

Answer (score 4):

I have an alternative for you:

Apache Flume is built by Cloudera and is primarily designed to get data in / out of HDFS.

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/FLUME/Index

There are pros and cons of each system, and all of them have certain reliability issues at high scale, but I can say that Flume is built in java so can use the primary HDFS library.

We use flume across lots of nodes to get data from our machines into HDFS and S3.

Comment: The best of it, that it comes with a lot of sinks/sources. And there are even more on Github. I really like flume.

Comment: I'm using the rpcSource and that's proving to be a little temperamental honestly.

Comment: Yep, I had to rewrite my own as well. But the rest of it is quite usable ;)

Answer (score 0):

Check the comparison of tools for collecting logs at https://groups.google.com/a/cloudera.org/forum/#!topic/flume-user/BMtsyGedcPo